# Double databind object of pair key value, for a dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to databind an html dropdown with an object consisted of pair key value that looks like this:

```
var myObject = { 
   'France': true,
   'Morocco': false,
   'US': false,
   'India': false
}
```

Only one attribute of the object can be true, and this attribute is represents the selected element of the drop down.

Here is my angular code:

```
<select class="form-control select select-items select-selected" #t (ngModelChange)="getNightlyType(t.options[t.selectedIndex].text)" [(ngModel)]="myObject[t.options[t.selectedIndex].text]">
    <option *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(myObject)" [ngValue]="myObject[key]">{{ key }}</option>
</select>
```

`getNightlyType()`: will set the value true to the selected element, and false to all the others as follow:

```
getNightlyType(country: any) {
  for (let element in myObject) {
    if (element !== country) {
      myObject[element] = false;
    } else {
      myObject[element] = true;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that if I give an object of countries with value true, it is not binded automatically to the gui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the perfect use for [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe to iterate your object, with that, you can easily use `selected` to initially capture the `true` property:

```html
<select (change)="selectCountry($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let item of myObject | keyvalue" [value]="item.key" [selected]="item.value">
    {{item.key}}
  </option>
</select>
```

A fork of Jude Raj's StackBlitz: **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-object-select-tntz4s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: That was as simple as reading this solution.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of two way binds, a clean approach would be to use one input and one change event listener.

- [value] calls getSelected(), which obtains the first key for which value is true in myObject
- (change) calls selectCountry() with the change event, from which we can obtain the selected value and call getNightlyType() to modify the object appropriately.

**dropdown.component.html**

```
<select [value]="getSelected()" (change)="selectCountry($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(myObject)" [ngValue]="myObject[key]">{{ key }}</option>
</select>
```

**dropdown.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  objectKeys = Object.keys;
  myObject = { 
   'France': false,
   'Morocco': true,
   'US': false,
   'India': false
  }

  getSelected(){
    for(const key in this.myObject){
      if(this.myObject[key] === true) return key;
    }
  }

  selectCountry(evt){
    this.getNightlyType(evt.target.value);
  }

  getNightlyType(country: any) {
    for (let element in this.myObject) {
      if (element !== country) {
        this.myObject[element] = false;
      } else {
        this.myObject[element] = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-object-select?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @zahma If this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. Thanks!